# Grey Video frames when using OpenCV Videocapture with GStreamer C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-streaming, gstreamer

[image: Received Frame]

Hey,
I am new to Gstreamer and want to send a video that is captured from a camera and manipulated with OpenCV over a network to the receiving part. The receiving part then read it and displays it. This shall be done in real-time. It basically works with the code/gstreamer settings below however as soon a frame is dropped (at least I think this is the reason) the video get corrupted in form of grey parts (attached picture).

OpenCV Sending Part:

```
cv::VideoWriter videoTransmitter("appsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! x264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.168.99 port=5000", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'), 10, videoTransmitter_imageSize, true);
```

OpenCV Receiving part:

```
cv::VideoCapture videoReceiver("udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

It basically works but I often get grey parts in the video which then stay for a bit until the video is displayed correctly. I guessed it happens always when a frame is dropped due to the transmission. However, how can I get rid of these grey/corrupted frames? Any Hints? Any Gstreamer parameters I need to set to tune result? Is there a better way to stream a video with opencv over network?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: how do you show/look at these frames? please take the [tour], review [mre] and [ask]

Comment: what i'm seeing is a partial video stream. the decoder hasn't been given an intra frame yet, or it noticed some corruption in the stream, so it starts with gray emptiness. it still tries to decode the updates. that is what you got there. -- networks drop packets. that's unavoidable and to be designed for. TCP implements acknowledgements and retransmissions but UDP does not. since you use UDP, you will lose data, and you did lose data.

Comment: work up a [mre] using just gstreamer processes, no OpenCV. then you know it's not an OpenCV problem.

Comment: Does the video recover after some time? If you have enough bandwidth in the network you can try to reduce the gop-size strongly. You can also try to capture your stream with vlc and use some reasonable network-cache size, which can help to not lose packets (on the receiver side, not on the network side).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Micka yes, it does recover after some time. The video is updating all the time, there is no stopping in the video. But the grey overlay is there for several seconds until its gone. What would you recommend to set the gop-size?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I was thinking about using TCP but isnt UDP always used for fast video transmission? I hoped that there is a better way (gstreamer parameter tunings? or something else) than using TCP but I can tryit with TCP too.

Comment: @ernsten what's the fps? What's the resolution? For example if you set the gop size to 1 you will always send full images. Please also try to display the stream in VLC, whether you see a similar behaviour. If everythzis fine thete, the problems are not on network level but pn receiver side.

Comment: @Micka I am sending with 10Hz and the resolution is 640x480. I will definitely try it with VLC next week and will check what happens when i decrease gop :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any mechanism in Gstreamer to detect corrupted frames, because this doesn't make sense.

In most modern video codec, frame aren't sent in full anymore, but split in slices (meaning only a small part of the frame). It can takes multiple intra packets (each containing multiple slices) to build a complete frame, and this is a good thing, because it makes your stream more resilient to errors, and allow multithreaded decoding of the slices (for example).

In order to achieve what you want, you have multiple solutions:

1. **Use RTP/RTCP instead of RTP over UDP only**. At least RTP contains a sequence number and "end of frame" markers so it possible to detect some packet drops. Gstreamer doesn't care about those by default unless you have started a RTP/RTCP session. If you set up a session with RTCP, you can have reports when some packets were dropped. I'm not sure there is a *pipeline* way to be informed when a packet is dropped, so you might still have to write an appsink in your gstreamer pipeline to add some code for detecting this event. However, this will tell you something is wrong, but not when it's ok to resume or how much wrong it is. In Gstreamer speak, it's called RTPSession, and you're interested in the [stats::XXX_nack_count properties](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtpmanager/rtpsession.html?gi-language=c#rtpsession:stats),
2. **Add some additional protocol** to compute the checksum of the encoder's output frame/NAL/packet and transmit out of band. Make sure the decoder also compute the checksum of incoming frame/NAL/packet and if doesn't match, you'll know it'll fail decoding. Beware of packet/frame reordering (typically B frames will be re-ordered after their dependencies) that could disturb your algorithm. Again, you have no way to know when to resume upon an error. Using TCP instead of UDP might be enough to fix it if you only have partial packet drop, but it'll fail to resume if it's a bandwidth issue (if the video bandwidth > network bandwidth, it'll collapse, since TCP **can't drop** packets to adapt)
3. **Use intra only video codec (like APNG, or JPEG)**. JPEG can also partially decode, but gstreamer's default software jpeg decoder doesn't output a partial JPEG frame.
4. **Set a closed and shorter GOP in your encoder**. Many encoder have a pseudo "gop = group of picture" parameter and count the frames in your decoder when decoding after an error. A GOP ensure that whatever the state of the encoding, after GOP frames, the encoder will emit an non-dependent group of frames (likely enough intra frame/slices to rebuild the complete frame). This will allow resuming after an error by dropping `GOP - 1` frames (you must decode them, but you can't *use* them, they might be corrupted), you'll need a way to detect the error, see point 1 or 2 above. For `x264enc` the parameter is called `key-int-max`. You might want to try also `intra-refresh=true` so the broken frame effect upon error will be shorter. The downside is an increase in bandwidth for the same video quality.
5. **Use a video codec with scalable video coding** (SVC instead of AVC for exemple). In that case, in case of decoding error, you'll get a lower quality instead of corrupted frame. There isn't any free SVC encoder I'm aware of in Gstreamer.
6. **Deal with it**. Compute a saturation map of the picture with OpenCV and compute its deviation & mean. If it's very different from the previous picture, stop computation until the GOP has elapsed and the saturation is back to expected levels.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. 

How can I start a RTP/RTCP seassion? Like I said I am new to Gstreamer and video transmission, I am using opencv in C++ and need to transfer the video in real-time over the network. Gstreamer was the first thing I found online that can be used in combination with opencv thats why I decided to try it. I can deal with a lower quality, everything is better than these grey frames. If you have some more "Hands-on/implementional" hints I would be very thankful :) Which value would you recommend for key-int-max?

Comment: For the RTP session, please follow the link and go to the top of the page for example command lines. However, OpenCV's appsink is already written and it doesn't account for RTP session stats, so you either have to copy the source for the VideoCapture and modify it yourself.

Comment: At first, I would try to set the `intra-refresh=true` on the encoder, so it should resume on a better frame resiliency. Then work with `key-int-max` (it depends on the target bitrate you can reach. The lower the GOP, the higher the bandwidth requirement for the same quality). Set key-int-max to 30 at first (it should resume after 1s) and increase or decrease until you've something acceptable from your processing pipeline. For a drone like network streaming the algorithm should be resilient for at least few seconds of video drop